# Transferring a working system drive from a linux server to new metal

Tags: linux, hard-drive, transfer, mail-server

I have a single drive linux mail server. I recently purchased a new server, can I move the hard-drive from the old system to the new machine and bootup? Since the kernel adds drivers during bootup, any changes should be automatic. Just looking for some insight to see if why I shouldn't do this, as I am planning to try this, as my fastest option for migrating to the new machine.